# The usage of "the" in a general statement

Tags: definite-articles

"Gas prices are going up."  Which of the following is also a general statement about gas prices:

> - The price of gasoline is going up.
> - The gas price is going up.

And could you tell me why? I have this question because although I know, for example, both "Tigers are big" and "The tiger is big" are generic constructions, but I am not sure how to use "the"  when it is a  noun phrase instead of a single noun.

Comment: "The price of gasoline is going up" is the standard and idiomatic generic statement. "Gas prices are going up" is another standard and idiomatic way of saying the same thing. "The tiger is big" is ambiguous because it can refer to the tiger in general or to a specific tiger, depending on context.

Comment: @BillFranke How about "Prices of gasoline are going up" or "The gas prices are going up"? Are they also correct to talk about the gas price in general?

Comment: Bill, I don't see why the Tiger example would seem ambiguous, to you. Saying "The tiger is big", would mean that the speaker is talking about one, particular Tiger.

Comment: @Tristan: Of all the felines (lions, tigers, cheetahs, jaguars, leopards, etc.), the tiger is the biggest.

Comment: I know that, Scott. The different types of Tigers vary greatly in size so, not all of them are bigger than other cats.

Comment: The example "Tigers are big" would refer to Tigers generally because, it is not mentioning any in particular.  "The tiger is big" would refer to one, particular Tiger because, it is using the word *the*, as well as the word *tiger*, which is singular.

Comment: @Tristan: So many things to say; so little space.  First of all, when you respond to a comment (in a new comment), it’s conventional to mention the author’s name, preceded by “@”, as in “@Scott”.  That way he gets notified.  See the **Replying in comments** paragraphs of [the **Comment formatting** section](http://english.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) of the Markdown Help page.

Comment: @Tristan: Secondly, how many types of tigers do you know about?  I mostly hear about Bengal and Siberian subspecies; [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiger) also mentions a Caspian tiger, also known as the Hyrcanian tiger, which is critically endangered or (probably) extinct.  Wikipedia says, “The tiger _(Panthera tigris)_ is the largest cat species…”  Are you talking about age?  Because, yes, tiger cubs are smaller than adults of many of the other species; duh.

Comment: @Tristan: Thirdly, I believe that most people would interpret “the tiger” in my sentence to mean the tiger _species_, not an individual.  That was the point of my comment –– to give an example where the phrase “the tiger” referred to many tigers (all tigers) rather than one, particular tiger.  //  Also, why are you capitalizing “Tiger” when it’s not the first word in the sentence?

Comment: @Scott, thanks for your comments about comments. Noted. I know that there are different types of tigers and that the Siberian type are the biggest of all (they are also the biggest of all cats). There are also South China tigers, Bali Tigers, Indochinese Tigers, Malayan tigers, Javan tigers and Sumatran tigers.

Comment: @Tristan: May I borrow your time machine?  :-)

Comment: @Scott: Regarding when you wrote "most people would interpret “the tiger” in my sentence to mean the tiger species, not an individual." Possibly but, it's not really necessary and may be ambiguous. You could just as easily have written "Of all the felines (lions, tigers, cheetahs, jaguars, leopards, etc.), **tigers** are the biggest."

Comment: With regard to generic tigers, see [this answer](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/000001.html). With regard to the OQ, _the_ is necessary in both cases because it is the price of gasoline, not anything else, that's being discussed. Both sentences are, however, grammatical, and there's no real reason to distinguish between them. They're just two different ways to say the same thing. It is the norm in every language to have many different ways of saying anything, most of which are unremarkable.

Comment: Or, as Kipling famously put it: "There are nine and sixty ways of constructing tribal lays, **And ∙ Every ∙ Single ∙ One ∙ Of ∙ Them ∙ Is ∙ Right!"**

Answer (score 1):

I would change your second example ("The gas price is going up") to "The price of gas is going up" or "Gas prices are going up."

Answer (score 0):

Both are general, but there are subtle differences in nuance. The first one is more standard: used both in daily conversation and in the news. The second one is rarely ever used in the States. I can't say if the other English speaking countries use it or not. But the feeling of the sentence is not native-like; it almost has hints of a dependent clause.
"The price of gas is going up ~~~.

Answer (score 0):

The crux of this question involves the pairing of subjects that appear near the beginning of the sentence (in the original example, *gasoline* and *prices*). I don't think that any general rule satisfactorily disposes of all such combinations.

Of the poster's two rewritten versions of the original example, "The price of gasoline is going up" sounds natural, but "The gas[oline] price is going up" does not.

On the other hand, consider the subject pair *relief* and *efforts* in the sentence "Relief efforts have been successful."  Rewriting this statement to match the models provided in the original post, I get "The relief effort has been successful" (which sounds natural) and "The effort for [or *toward* or *in* or *of*] relief has been successful" (which sounds awkward).

Finally, consider the subject pair *budget* and *deficit*, in the sentence "Budget deficits are increasing." Here, both "The budget deficit is increasing" and "The deficit in the budget is increasing" sound natural and have virtually identical meanings. But to a U.S. reader, both versions have a more specific meaning than the original plural example does because both implicitly focus on the federal government's budget deficit rather than on budget deficits in general.

To sum up, what sounds right and makes sense in a particular instance depends on so many complicating factors that no usefully predictive general rule governing where and how to use *the* is possible.